# Outdoor lamp installation without outlet box

Tags: receptacle, mounting, lamp, brackets

I am replacing my old outdoor lamp. The new lamp has an X-shaped mounting bracket. However, my outlet does not have an outlet box (see pic), or may be there is one but the stucco has covered it. There is just a horizontal metal strip that I can see.

[image]

The old lamp was screwed into the screw in the center. However, the new lamp's bracket does not have such a feature.

Is there a way to install the "X" bracket to the horizontal strip? I don't want to break stucco to install the outlet box.

Comment: There may be a metal box there and the edges are covered with stucco. Those two outside screws are probably screwed into the tabs of a metal box.

Comment: That's an answer @JimStewart

Comment: Let me try removing the plate and see if the X bracket can be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Weather metal or plastic there looks to be a box in this location. Removing the old screws and putting the new ones to hold the fixture will be fine, I believe it is not metal because I can see a 3rd wire not connected to anything a metal box would require the box to be bonded. Pull the old screws put up the new fixture, if metal used the bare copper to the new fixture bare copper if plastic just connect the black and white to the new fixtures black and white.